# Logical operator precedence in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Why does this expression return False instead of True ?

`$true -or $false -and $false`

`-and` should take precedence over `-or`, as confirmed by [Microsoft Powershell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-7.1).

But it looks like the expression is evaluated as `($true -or $false) -and $false` instead of `$true -or ($false -and $false)` !

Can someone explain to me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: "In the following list, operators are listed in the order that they are evaluated. Operators on the same line, or in the same group, have equal precedence"

Comment: This line induced me in error : _"The list resumes here with the following operators in precedence order:"_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The linked documentation does *not* state that `-and` takes precedence over `-or` - instead, it states that **`-and` and `-or` - perhaps surprisingly<sup>[1]</sup> - have *equal* precedence**<sup>[2]</sup> in PowerShell.

Thus:

```sh
$true -or $false -and $false
```

is - due to implied left-associativity - evaluated as:

```sh
($true -or $false) -and $false  # -> $false
```

In other words: Use `(...)` to override this left-associativity on demand:

```sh
$true -or ($false -and $false)  # -> $true
```

---

<sup>[1] See [GitHub issue #8512](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8512) for a discussion.</sup>

<sup>[2] The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence) list `-and -or -xor` on the *same line*, implying that that all these operators have *equal* precedence.</sup>

Comment: I'm used to the standard way (should I say "correct way") of evaluating logical operators, where and always takes precedence over or, so this comes as a real surprise and will definitively be joining my collection of PowerShell gotcha's !

Comment: It comes as a surprise to me as well. More surprisingly I never had a bug because of that in practice. That's propably because I tend to use `(...)` in boolean expressions to express my intend instead of relying on precedence.

Comment: Indeed, @zett42, `(...)` is a pragmatic way to enforce and signal the desired precedence, without having to / making the reader think too hard about the built-in precedence, which is hard to remember, given how many operators PowerShell has.